# php prepared statement with wildcards

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a prepared statement using LIKE and wildcards:

```
$sql = "select id,ra from targets where ra like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

This works fine when I bind a parameter value like "123" but does not work if I bind one with a period, for example "123.".  I want to get all values that look like:

```
123.12
123.48
123.52
etc.
```

but this isn't working (I just get all rows that contain 123 anywhere in the string). Is there a problem entering the period into the prepared statement?

Comment: what do you mean with "isn't working"   you have error  ?   .. wrong result ?   no result ?   .. explain better

Comment: I get the wrong result: I get rows returned with "123" anywhere in the string: for example 258.526123.  What I want is rows that contain "123." but the period is not being matched.

Comment: This is not true. LIKE won't get you anything like that. Post here a Complete Verifiable example that anyone can run and confirm

Answer (score -1):

What data type are your columns, I tested this with string and double types and like worked for me with no issue (v 5.5.46), if you aren't having luck with it maybe give Regexp a try. You would need to wrap the punctuation in square brackets to prevent it from being used as an operator.

Try:

```
SELECT id, ra
FROM targets
WHERE ra REGEXP '123[.]';
```

Which for a binding would look like:

```
// Note no "" around question mark (would cause it to eval as the expression).
$sql = "SELECT id, ra FROM targets WHERE ra REGEXP ?";
```

MySQL [Regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

**EDIT**

Added a reason to try regexp, as well as listing the tests I tried to duplicate the issue OP was having.

Comment: Why should one to try regexp? what's wrong with like?

Comment: original post said like wasn't working. But I went back and added some descriptive text to be clearer.

Comment: The data type of the column is FLOAT. The following query produces the wrong result: select ra from targets where ra like CONCAT('%', 123., '%'); but the following query produces the correct result: select ra from targets where ra like CONCAT('%', '123.', '%'); but I don't know how to put those single quotes in my prepared statement?

Comment: @MeganCrane could you add an example of your implementation of bind for this query?

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'd', $ra);`

Comment: @MeganCrane just a guess since I don't have a setup to test this (you should really add more of your php to the original question so we can try to duplicate your issue :) ), but try changing that 'd' to an 's'. You want to string compare your variable to the float column if you are using like, if this sends '123' instead of '123.' in the prepare you will need to make the `$ra` value a string before preparing.